# Нужно сделать circle progress bar с круглым маркером в конце вместо квадратного

Tags: android, progress-bar

Я скачал и подключил библиотеку *Holo Circle Progress bar*, но мне хотелось бы, чтобы вместо этого ужасного квадрата был круг, как в стандартном приложении от *google deskclock*
[image: из этого][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрел в исходники, но это ничего не дало, только загадочный `drawable` с этим самым кругом, который даже в xml-разметках не используется

Как заменить квадрат на круг?

Comment: [исодники](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/packages/apps/DeskClock/res/drawable/bg_circle_pink.xml?av=f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идет об этой [библиотеке](https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar/tree/master/library), то могу посоветовать следующее:
После "// draw the thumb square at the correct rotated position", вы должны нарисовать не square (квадрат), а circle (круг), используя метод `drawCircle (float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint)` класса `Canvas`. Это проще, чем квадрат, так как ничего не надо поворачивать.

Я подозреваю, что будет что-то вроде:

```
if (isThumbEnabled()) {
        // draw the thumb circle at the correct rotated position
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(progressRotation - 90);
        canvas.drawCircle (mThumbPosX, mThumbPosY, mThumbRadius, mThumbColorPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Comment: спасибо!
Как раз я подумал на этот метод